# Remove white space from a text file in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a file in the following text format:

```
sagchjvcsj    kbschjsdchs      sudbjsdbl  avhsdvbas
sdvbchjbvsdjc    kbsadcsadk    kskbjdsdcksajdbc  kansjdnas ajksbdajsdk
```

with out of sequence `white spaces` between the words. I want to remove all the `extra white spaces` and leave only `1 white space` between the words. My working is:

```
private void buttonBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialogImage.Filter = "Text files | .txt";
    openFileDialogImage.Multiselect = false;

    DialogResult result = openFileDialogImage.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBoxFileName.Text = openFileDialogImage.FileName;
    }
}

private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String path = openFileDialogImage.FileName;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        string s = String.Empty;
        while ((s = reader.ReadToEnd()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
    }
}
```

`buttonBrowse` is correctly displaying the file path in `textBoxFileName` but when I press the Go button (`buttonGo`), program is freezing with no output. Can someone please guide.

Comment: Hit `Break All` while the program is running, and see where execution is. Step through and see what's happening.

Comment: @GrantWinney, True that. Thanks

Comment: @Blorgbeard Execution is on line `while ((s = reader.ReadToEnd()) != null)` and it has a red cross in `reader` saying `EndOfStream = Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on the top of the call stack.`

Comment: see my answer.  MSDN is actually helpful sometimes for simple stuff!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're while loop never ends.

> while ((s = reader.ReadToEnd()) != null)

That [ReadToEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a string every time it loops (when at the end it is an empty string - Not null.

> If the current position is at the end of the stream, returns an empty
>   string

You need to either remove the while loop and just do:

```
s = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

or change null to string.Empty

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It has eliminated the freezing problem but it is not doing any change to the original file which has out of sequence white space problem. Any ideas why?

Comment: You're not saving it is one reason.

Comment: How to save? Actually I also need to first remove `extra spaces` to `one comma` and save it?

Comment: @RehanKhan The question as asked has been answered. If you have another question, you should post it as a new question. Or, you know, try to figure it out yourself first!

Comment: I'll give you a hint.  Stream Reader only reads the string.  You need another tool to "write" it.  And of course you need to make sure you don't lock the file while reading it.